# SQL Server 2008 (express edition) Configuration - with Active directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, networking, configuration, active-directory

I have 3 computers. I have installed windows server + Active Directory on one pc. There are two other PCs registered with active directory. Those two PCs have installed SQL server(express) 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 separately. Here is my network. :)

[image]

Now I want to communicate with SQL server to access db through my development machine. Do I have to install SQL in that machine too ?

How ever I need to use PC1 as my SQL server machine.

How do I connect to SQL db located in PC1 from PC2 ??

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to your question

Now I want to communicate with SQL server to access db through my development machine. Do I have to install SQL in that machine too ?  **No**

How do I connect to SQL db located in PC1 from PC2 ?? on your config file use this as the connection string.
**`Data Source=PC1Name\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`**
But if you want to view the data on PC1 without Visual Studio you need at least the SQL Server Management Studio Management Tools.  If your useing express by default it is installed as an instance thats why the data source on the connection string is PC1Name\SQLEXPRESS.  Usually the instance name is SQLEXPRESS.